# How to deal with different types of information in a text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm downloading a text file and using the information from it to create several objects.

I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: readerView.url
                                                  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                     error: NULL];

NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for(NSString *line in lines)
{
    NSArray *params = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *label1 = [params objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *label2 = [params objectAtIndex:1];
    float weight = [[params objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    int x1 = [[params objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
    int y1 = [[params objectAtIndex:4] intValue];
    int x2 = [[params objectAtIndex:5] intValue];
    int y2 = [[params objectAtIndex:6] intValue];
    int type = [[params objectAtIndex:7] intValue];

    [graph addComponents:label1:label2 :weight :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :type];
}
```

An example of a line in the text file is like so:

`A,B,6.0,270,190,150,190,1`

So it's pretty basic. What I wanted to do though was for either the first or last line of the text file, have a URL which would trigger another download for an image. I can't think of what would be the best way to achieve this. In my mind I'm thinking something like this in pseudo code:

If(line = first line)
trigger download
else
go through params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KennyTM is right, but I would do it the other way around because `,` is a valid URL character for some schemes and invalid for others, so it's possible (if unlikely) to get a false positive. Parsing the line as a URL will return nil if the line is not a valid URL and then you can parse the line as the formatted data you expect in absence of a URL.

```
for(NSString *line in lines) {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:line];
    if (url) {
        // trigger download...
    } else {
        NSArray *params = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        // Do stuff with params
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't seem to be checking whether it is a URL or not. I put an NSLog after the `if (url)` and it seems to get printed regardless of whether it's a url or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to check if the line is in the valid params format. If not, try to parse as URL.

Assuming the URL doesn't contain exactly 7 commas,

```
for(NSString *line in lines) {
    NSArray *params = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if ([params count] == 8) {
       // go through params
    } else {
       NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:line];
       if (url) {
          // trigger download...
       }
    }
}
```

This way the URL can be placed anywhere in the file.

Comment: Yep that's working great! I knew what I wanted to do just couldn't quite think of an efficient way. Thanks Kenny! :)

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with `NSURL URLWithString:line` not working as expected. I've put in a breakpoint and run through the code and the variable `url` is getting set even when a string that isn't a URL is being passed to it. I thought if this was the case then it would return nil?

Comment: Okay I've found out a peculiar reason why this is happening but I don't understand why. Basically, for the sake of keeping my text file neat, I put a few spaces into some of the parameters. E.G - `B,C,3.0,150,190,30 ,40 ,1` Somehow while debugging I happened to notice that the lines with spaces in were working fine but the lines without spaces were being picked up as URLs. Any idea why this is?